# Time scale won't convert dates to numbers

Tags: d3.js

I am having trouble with using the time scale. I have dates in the format 'YYYYMMDD', I parse these with:

```
parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse
```

I set the domain to static dates using the same above function. I can see the dates in correct format in the console. But when applying the scale function x, it returns 'NaN' WAT?

It's probably something small I'm not seeing, it's driving me mad...

Code can be found here: http://bl.ocks.org/pberden/5668581

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you call `d3.nest`. According to the [spec](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-nest_key)

> The key function will be invoked for each element in the input array, and must return a **string** identifier that is used to assign the element to its group.

You convert the `Day` in your csv file to a `Date` but then, as you are building a map from the array using `d3.nest()`, the invocation of the `key` function turns this `Date` to a `String` by doing an implicit conversion.

To fix this I think you could try to force your `line` generator to turn a `String` into `Date` like so

```
var line = d3.svg.line()    
 .x(function(d) { return x(new Date(d.key)); })
 .y(function(d) { return y(d.values.Value); });
```

Comment: Great! that was indeed the problem. Thanks a lot!

As you can see in the bl.ocks the lines are visible now.